# Combining pdftk strings for specific pages

Tags: powershell, pdftk

I've checked "Similar questions" and went through a lot of search but I can't seem to find a way to combine the snippets I already figured out; would be awesome if someone is able to help.

> Using pdftk, alternatively running through PowerShell

I got two .pdf files (f.e.: A=1000 pages, B=5000 pages) which I need to combine in a specific way to generate a new .pdf file. In detail I need page 1-3, 4-6[...] of file A merged with page 1-4, 4-8[...] of file B with a blank page between 1-3 & 4-6.

So far I figured how to burst the files, add a blank page and combine them to a new .pdf file. Yet I'm only able to that for one needed document at a time (a new file with 8 pages).

```
pdftk fileC.pdf fileD.pdf cat output fileE.pdf
pdftk A=fileE.pdf B=blankpage.pdf cat A1-1 B1-1 A2-4 output conclusion.pdf
```

Now I'm wondering if there's a way to output the complete file with a command? Otherwise I'd have to do it for every merge of two long files.

Thanks in advance!